# iterate through all rows in specific column openpyxl

Tags: excel, python-2.7, openpyxl

I cannot figure out how to iterate through all rows in a specified column with openpyxl.

I want to print all of the cell values for all rows in column "C"

Right now I have:

```
from openpyxl import workbook
path = 'C:/workbook.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(filename = path)
ws=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet3')

for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if column == 'C':
            print cell.value
```

Comment: What's `ws`? How did you use `openpyxl`? Please give some more details about the goal you're trying to achive or else every answer will be based over assumptions.

Comment: @danielhadar I think ws is short for work_sheet.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can specify a range to iterate over with [`ws.iter_rows()`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html?highlight=iter_rows#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_rows):

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/workbook.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet3']
for row in ws.iter_rows('C{}:C{}'.format(ws.min_row,ws.max_row)):
    for cell in row:
        print cell.value
```

Edit: per your comment you want the cell values in a list:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('c:/_twd/2016-06-23_xlrd_xlwt/input.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
mylist = []
for row in ws.iter_rows('A{}:A{}'.format(ws.min_row,ws.max_row)):
    for cell in row:
        mylist.append(cell.value)
print mylist
```

Comment: Is string argument for `ws.iter_rows()` still valid? I needed to use `ws.iter_rows(min_row=ws.min_row, max_row=ws.max_row)`

Comment: With python3, I need to use `for row in ws.iter_rows(ws.min_row,ws.max_row)` or `for row in ws` to make it work.

Comment: This whole "A1:A123"-style business seems to not or no longer valid, do like the others have suggested or have a look at the definition of the current implementation: `def iter_rows(self, min_row=None, max_row=None, min_col=None, max_col=None, values_only=False):`

Answer (score 77):

Why can't you just iterate over column 'C' (version 2.4.7):

```
for cell in ws['C']:
   print cell.value
```

Answer (score 12):

You can also do this.

```
for row in ws.iter_rows():
   print(row[2].value)
```

With this you are still iterating through the rows (but not the cells) and only pulling the values from column C in the row to print.

Answer (score 7):

Some of the solutions above don't quite work very well (maybe because of latest version of 'openpyxl'). After trying out different things, I used this:

## Printing all rows with all columns:

```
import openpyxl

sheet = openpyxl.load_workbook('myworkbook.xlsx')['Sheet1']
# Iterating through All rows with all columns...
for i in range(1, sheet.max_row+1):
    row = [cell.value for cell in sheet[i]] # sheet[n] gives nth row (list of cells)
    print(row) # list of cell values of this row
```

## Printing all rows with specific columns (e.g. 'E' to 'L'):

```
# For example we need column 'E' to column 'L'
start_col = 4 # 'E' column index
end_col = 11 # 'L' column index
for i in range(1, sheet.max_row+1):
    row = [cell.value for cell in sheet[i][start_col:end_col+1]]
    print(row) # list of cell values of this row
```

Please keep these points in mind:

- **sheet[N]** gives the list of '**Cell**' objects of *Nth* row. (N is a number starting from 1)
- To get the first column cell of a row, use **sheet[N][0]**. (Because **sheet[N]** is a '**tuple**' which can be indexed starting from zero 0).

Answer (score 2):

it can go as:

```
import openpyxl
path = 'C:/workbook.xlsx'
# since is a print, read_only is useful for making it faster.
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = path, read_only=True)
# by sheet name 
ws=wb['Sheet3']

# non-Excel notation is col 'A' = 1, col 'B' = 2, col 'C' = 3.
# from row = 1 (openpyxl sheets starts at 1, not 0) to no max
for row in ws.iter_cols(min_row=1, min_col=3, max_col=3): 
    # for each row there is one cell object (since min_col = max_col)
    for cell in row:
        # so we print the value
        print(f'C{row}: ', cell.value)
```

Comment: I find this answer the most useful for me. Good explanation. You can also use the combination of `ws.min_row` and `ws.max_row` to scan all used rows (i.e. not the whole worksheet) keeping column 3 fixed (i.e. C) in the iterator, for example:
`ws.iter_rows(min_row=ws.min_row, max_row=ws.max_row, min_col=3, max_col=3)`

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this. I'm not sure what I'm doing but it does avoid the cells with no values.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'exelfile.xlsx')
ws = wb['sheet1']

for col in ws['A']:
    print (col.value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use coordinate property in cell object.

coordinate property contains cell address in string format.

For example,

```
from openpyxl import workbook
path = 'C:/workbook.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(filename = path)
ws=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet3')

for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if 'C' in cell.coordinate:
            print cell.value
```

Answer (score -1):

```
listaClientes =[]
    for row in datos.iter_rows(min_row=2, min_col=3, max_col=3):
        for cell in row:
            listaClientes.append(cell.value)
```