# Openpyxl: How do I get the values of a specific column?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm writing a program that searches through the first row of a sheet for a specific value ("Filenames"). Once found, it iterates through that column and returns the values underneath it (rows 2 through x).

I've figured out how to iterate through the first row in the sheet, and get the cell which contains the specific value, but now I need to iterate over that column and print out those values. How do I do so?

```
import os
import sys
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def main():

    column_value = 'Filenames'

    wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
    script = wb["Script"]

# Find "Filenames"
for col in script.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=1):
    for name in col:
        if (name.value == column_value):
            print("Found it!")
            filenameColumn = name
            print(filenameColumn)
    
# Now that we have that column, iterate over the rows in that specific column to get the filenames
for row in filenameColumn: # THIS DOES NOT WORK
    print(row.value)

main()
```

Comment: I presume this is homework otherwise you could just use a Pandas Dataframe.. it is more straight forward

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iterate through all rows in specific column openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619471/iterate-through-all-rows-in-specific-column-openpyxl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually iterating over rows and cells, not columns and names here:

```
for col in script.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=1):
    for name in col:
```

if you rewrite it that way, you can see you get a cell, like this:

```
for row in script.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=1):
    for cell in row:
        if (cell.value == column_value):
            print("Found it!")
            filenameCell = cell
            print(filenameCell)
```

So you have a cell.  You need to get the column, which you can do with `cell.column` which returns a column index.

Better though, than iterating over just the first row (which iter_rows with min and max row set to 1 does) would be to just use `iter_cols` - built for this.  So:

```
for col in script.iter_cols():
      # see if the value of the first cell matches
      if col[0].value == column_value:
         # this is the column we want, this col is an iterable of cells:
         for cell in col:
            # do something with the cell in this column here
```

Comment: Worth noting that `iter_cols` is not available in `read_only` mode

Comment: This will loop through **all** cells of **all** columns before it gets to the header. Probably better to search the first row and then loop over the rows/columns using min_col & max_col = cell.column.

Comment: It won't loop through any cells in a column for which the first cell (col[0].value) isn't the header we're looking for